# How to restore Mysql db through java application from backup.sql file created using mysqldump

Tags: java, mysql, runtime.exec

Hi I am unable to restore the backup.sql file, that was created by mysqldump command run through java runtime.exec() method,through my java application using a string array command in the runtime.exec().

I read through whole lot of similar posts .......but still could not resolve this issue.

The code snippet is as below:

```
String dbname ="db2";
String dbuser = "root";
String dbpassword = "1243";
String sourcepath = JTextField2.getText();
boolean status=false;

String[] command = new String []{"mysql","-u "+dbuser+" -p",dbpassword,dbname,"-e","source "+sourcepath};

       try{
            Process runtimeprocess=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            int processComplete=runtimeprocess.waitFor();
            if(processComplete==0){
            status=true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Restored successfully!!");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Restore failed!!");
            }

        }catch(IOException ioe){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe);
        }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have your mysql program added to to the OS environment path because this code look like it requires that or your need to start the program in the same directory where is mysql program is.. What you also can do to dynimally get MySQL install dir is to query the database with `SELECT @@basedir` and use that path in your program

Comment: I added the mysql to the OS environment path ....but the application just keeps on running ...and i had to kill it....also when i checked the task manager after executing the codes the mysql.exe appeared as running... :(

Comment: I took the mysqldump using same command as above except it was just string instead of string array....

Comment: @RaymondNijland any thoughts ....

Comment: Finally got resolved it was an silly issue due to use of forward slash "/" in the xx.sql file path.... :)